# Would people in Seoul be bothered by a big baggage in the subway/bus?

Tags: public-transport, south-korea, seoul

The box in question is a 55cm cube. Do we also need to buy a ticket for it or something?

Comment: To people voting to close as "primarily opinion-based", note that the question is about whether people in general would be annoyed, not whether you personally would be annoyed. And "Do we also need to buy a ticket for it?" is a question that must be objectively answerable.

Comment: Blaszard's answer is correct, except that there are more elevators and escalators than his/her answer suggests. Please note that the subway in Seoul is crowded at rush hours, so YOU may be annoyed riding it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you don't need to buy a separate ticket. It is very common to see tourists carry a large baggage in public transport, especially the train from and to the airport.

There are always some people who are annoyed with it, but they are not the majority. If you care about those 10% people you can do nothing.

The more hassle is that it is common that you are unable to find any elevator in the metro station, and also there is no escalator. So you must carry your baggage on the stairs.

Comment: `The more hassle is that it is common that you are unable to find any elevator in the metro station, ` that's not true at all. Metro stations in Seoul are abundant with many accessibility options. In other cities and surrounding cities you might not be so lucky, but it's definitely uncommon to **not** have an elevator.

Comment: @insidesin Maybe my English is not clear but I meant, it is *very difficult* to find an elevator. It is common you can’t find an elevator, even if it exists, since it is usually located in obscure places.

Comment: Yeah and I'm telling you that that is not true. There's no such thing as an obscure place when you're talking about Seoul subway. They have multiple exits, entrances and all link together. Not only that, there are huge signs and directions on the street level. In no way is it difficult to find the elevator, and in every station there are usually 1 or 2+.

Comment: I am not sure for Seoul, but in Busan, there are signs showing the closest elevator. The only problem is that they look like Toilets sign (a man, a woman and a child standing next to each other).